# Better way to join tables?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, join, view

I am posting a simplified version of my search, basically joining multiple tables in **SQL 2008**

```
select * from t1 
inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
inner join t3 on t2.id = t3.id
inner join t4 on t3.id = t4.id 
inner join t5 on t4.id = t5.id
```

I would like to know is there a way to keep a part of this query stored as an object. Not results but the query logic.

Let say I want to reuse

```
inner join t3 on t2.id = t3.id 
inner join t4 on t3.id = t4.id
inner join t5 on t4.id = t5.id
```

in different queries, something like

```
select * from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
inner join t_stored on t_stored.id = t3.id
```

I was thinking of having t_stored defined as a view, or function or a stored procedure (both expecting a parameter), but I am not really sure how would that affect performance. 
Is it better to keep it all in a main query no matter how complex it would get on the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know MS SQL performance is purely based on how the query execution plan gets generated and how it gets cached for better hit for execution context threads. The option of reusing joins by creating views is a good option but you will not get any advantage until keys are matched.

The question of reuse still remains; the view is the best option but the performance varies drastically if you don't need then in result set and right clustered index gets hit by the reusing query.

My personal experience suggests the best performance is achieved by having all these tables joined in the query as needed. As it allows you to get more control on query, just by modifying queries to have EXISTS statements than using JOINs (if you are not expecting those table fields in result set.)

see how plans gets cached by having a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a definitive answer to your question. Different databases have different optimizations. My gut feeling, assuming your example represents joining on (hopefully) properly indexed FK constraints, is it should not make a difference or not a substantial one.
Creating a view for often used data may even improve performance by allowing the DBMS to better cache the view.
However without actually trying it out and looking at the execution plan of both options I cannot be sure, which is what you should probably do.